# Undefined control sequence while using pdflatex

Tags: latex

I am trying to use the `moderncv` package for making my resume. I will admit, I have never played around with latex, so that is what is causing the problems maybe.

I get this error when trying I run:

`pdflatex file.tex`:

```
\@extrainfo ->\ComputerMouse {\weblink 
                                       { www.random.com}}
```

What I am doing wrong in this? Here is the line from the tex file:

```
\extrainfo{\ComputerMouse{\weblink{ www.random.com}}}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Cause it used to work earlier on my Ubuntu 10.04 but now on 10.10 it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `\weblink` command. Try `\url` instead.  (You'll need to add `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the preamble of your document to get the `\url` command.)